# RabbitMQ/MassTransit TLS instant handshake timeout

Tags: .net, ssl, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are having an issue where 2 very specific servers seem to have trouble establishing a TLS connection with our instance of RabbitMQ. The clients are .NET projects that connect to Rabbit via MassTransit. We are certain that the issue isn't code related as the exact same package is deployed and installed on each server.
Talking to the network engineers, we were told all the servers involved (Working and not working) were created off the exact same image and there is no firewall sat between the servers in question as it is all internal app servers. 
On the working servers, the apps connect fine, and the connection appears in the RabbitMQ connection tab, for the servers that don’t work, we get the error in the program:

```
Service cannot be started. MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect failed: DfSTGRabbitMQ@dfstgapp01.************.co.uk:5671/stg ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 cou...
```

Looking at the RabbitMQ logs, this all we get when the apps attempt to connect to Rabbit:

```
2018-07-20 16:08:08.011 [info] <0.2236.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.2236.0> (10.1.123.102:60341 -> 10.1.123.102:5671)
2018-07-20 16:08:08.011 [warning] <0.2236.0> closing AMQP connection <0.2236.0> (10.1.123.102:60341 -> 10.1.123.102:5671):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

We are very confused as the servers and program is identical but one server it connects fine and the other it can’t seem to establish a TLS connection. Has anybody else run into this issue and could help? Any settings we may have missed or something we need to look at?

Thanks